# Electric field to repel charged particles

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there anyway to create an electric field (or a modify it ) that would repel both positively and negatively charged particles.

Comment: Charged particles [can't enter regions of sufficiently strong *magnetic* fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror), but how strong depends on a bunch of details of the particles' motion.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "repel." If you mean a naive thing where an object with an electric field repels charges, then no. Changing the sign of the charge will change "repel" to "attract."

Maybe you could have some such thing as, electric charges get stuck in a barrier because and electric field shoves them against the side of the barrier. Where non-charged particles can get through the holes in the barrier.

Or conceivably you could have some such thing as positive charges get deflected to the left, and negative to the right. It's not really the same thing as "repel" but maybe it's good enough? It might be pretty delicate since it will depend on the details of the speed the charged particles are moving, and their masses.